# How to hlookup from one worksheet to another and repeat for multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet (sheet 1) with 272 districts (column D4:D275) and each row has 11 categories (category names E3:O3) (See image 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFnaf.png

I need to rearrange this data (in sheet 2) so that each category has its own row (ie 272*11 rows altogether). (See image 2):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvfXS.png

I know this requires hlookup but I don't know how to write the VBA code for it. Please can somebody tell me what the code I require is and explain what each step does as I will have to do this on a number of different documents so will need to know how to adjust the code.

Let me know if more info is needed

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here are the images:
Image 1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mFnaf.png
Image 2: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wvfXS.png

Comment: Edit your question to include images in it.

Comment: Sound like a typical case for `Unpivot`. You might want to google that. Here are two examples which should work for you: http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel OR here (with a YouTube video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUXJLzqlEPk

Comment: For each cell in Sheet1-columnA, loop 1 to 11 in Sheet2 copying Sheet1-ColumnA value and the concatenation of Category & loop number.

Answer (score 1):

based on the screenshots attached, this will do the job which will add the values respectively in the Columns A, B and C

```
Count = 4

For i = 4 To 18
    For j = 5 To 15
        Cells(Count, 1).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
        Cells(Count, 2).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
        Cells(Count, 3).Value = Cells(3, j).Value
        Count = Count + 1
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: This code is clear and compact. Just needs the limits to encompass all data, and setting the sheet names (on the left of equal sign `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(blah, blah)` whereas on the right `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(blah, blah)`). +1 for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the formula you are supposed to be using on screen, the same forumla can be used through VBA macro code by using Application.WorksheetFunction

```
=VLOOKUP(XXXX)
```

can be written in Macro as

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(XXXX)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need a way of repeating the function differently otherwise I would have to write it out 272 times

Comment: @joe `for i=1 to 272`?

Comment: I would need to change the row index number for each formula

Answer (score 0):

Try with below. Kindly alter

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim incre As Long
    Dim distr As String
    Set r = Range("D4:K6")
    incre = 4
    incre2 = 4
    For Each cell In r
        If cell Like "District*" Then
            distr = cell.Value
        Else
            Range("B" & incre).Value = cell.Value
            Range("A" & incre).Value = distr
            incre = incre + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are number of ways of achieving what you are trying to accomplish.

***1. Using formula***

In Cell `A4` of `Sheet2` enter the following formula and drag/copy down as required

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$4,FLOOR((ROW(Sheet1!D4)-ROW(Sheet1!$D$4))/11,1),0)
```

In Cell `C4` of `Sheet2`  enter the following formula and drag/copy down as required

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$E$4,FLOOR((ROW(Sheet1!E4)-ROW(Sheet1!$E$4))/11,1),MOD(ROW(Sheet1!D4)-ROW(Sheet1!$D$4),11))
```

***2. Using VBA***

**Method I -** Calculate values from `Sheet1` and update the range in `Sheet2`

```
Sub Demo1()
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long, CategoryCnt As Long, temp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
    CategoryCnt = 11    '->enter number of categories
    lastRow = srcWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    '->last row with data
    lastCol = srcWS.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    '->last column with data

    For i = 4 To (lastRow - 4) * CategoryCnt
        destWS.Cells(i, 1) = srcWS.Cells(Int((i - 4) / CategoryCnt) + 4, 4)
        destWS.Cells(i, 3) = srcWS.Cells(Int((i - 4) / CategoryCnt) + 4, ((i - 4) Mod CategoryCnt) + 5)
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**Method II -** Enter formula in `Sheet2` range

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long, CategoryCnt As Long, temp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
    CategoryCnt = 11
    lastRow = srcWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = srcWS.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    destWS.Range("A4").Formula = "=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$4,FLOOR((ROW(Sheet1!D4)-ROW(Sheet1!$D$4))/11,1),0)"
    destWS.Range("C4") = "=OFFSET(Sheet1!$E$4,FLOOR((ROW(Sheet1!E4)-ROW(Sheet1!$E$4))/11,1),MOD(ROW(Sheet1!D4)-ROW(Sheet1!$D$4),11))"
    Range("A4:C4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=destWS.Range("A4:C" & (lastRow - 4) * 11), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.

See image for reference:

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]